# V,W,U are vector spaces over F. Given f and g are linear transformations s.t. f: V -> W and g: W -> U. Show that g o f : V -> U is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

So this is where i'm at with it...

$$ \text{So given V,W,U are vector fields over a common field F}$$
$$ \ \ f:V \to W \ \\g:W\to U\\ \text{Are both linear transformations}\\    $$

$$
 \left\{ v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n} \right\} \text{is an ordered basis of V}
$$

$$
\left\{ w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{m} \right\} \text{is an ordered basis of W}
$$

$$
\left\{ u_{1},u_{2},...,u_{k} \right\} \text{is an ordered basis of U}
$$

$$$$

$$
\\ 
\forall v\in V \ \text{&}\  a,b,c\in F \
$$

$$
 \\ f(v) = f(a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2} + \ ...\ + a_{n}v_{n})\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =a_{1}f(v_{1}) + a_{2}f(v_{2}) + \ ...\ + a_{n}f(v_{n}) \in W \\ \ \ \ \ \ =b_{1}w_{1} + b_{2}w_{2} + \ ...\ + b_{m}w_{m}
$$
$$ $$
$$ 
g\left( f\left( v \right) \right)=g\left(a_{1}f(v_{1}) + a_{2}f(v_{2}) + \ ...\ + a_{n}f(v_{n})  \right)\\ \ = g\left( b_{1}w_{1} + b_{2}w_{2} + \ ...\ + b_{m}w_{m}  \right)\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   =b_{1}g\left( w_{1} \right) + b_{2}g\left( w_{2} \right) + \ ...\ + b_{m}g\left( w_{m} \right) \in U \\= c_{1}u_{1} + c_{2}u_{2} + \ ...\ + c_{k}u_{k} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

Is this sufficient enough to show that the composition of f and g is also a linear transformation?

Comment: Why are you using bases. All you need to do is show that if $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ are vectors and $\alpha$ is a scalar, then $(g\circ f)(\mathbf{u}+\alpha\mathbf{v}) = (g\circ f)(\mathbf{u}) + \alpha(g\circ f)(\mathbf{v})$.

Comment: No, this is not sufficient. You have not proven that $g\circ f$ is either additive *or* homogeneous.

Comment: So essentially did I just reiterate the fact that f and g are linear transformations?

Comment: No, you need to **use** the fact that $f$ and $g$ are linear transformations in order to *prove* that $g\circ f$ is also a linear transformation. To “reiterate” is to repeat. If all you do is *repeat* the fact that $f$ and $g$ are linear transformations, then you are not proving anything about $g\circ f$.

Comment: Didn’t I use their linearity though. I basically said f(v) is a linear combination of what f does to the basis vectors. That leverages the fact that linear transformations have the property f(av) = af(v) and f(a_1v_1 + a_2v_2)= a_1f(v_1) + a_2f(v_2) etc. And since that linear combination belongs to W, g (which is also linear by assumption) acting on that linear combination will exhibit all the same properties we want and yield a vector in U. It almost seems trivial because whatever f spits out will be a suitable vector for g to act on. But I suppose that’s not the correct way to think about it

Comment: What you write does not, let me repeat, does **not** make sense, and does **not** prove, in any way, that $g\circ f$ is linear. All you are saying is that the outputs of $f$ make sense as inputs for $g$, but that is true for **any** pair of composable functions, whether they are linear or not. Simply put: what you are looking it is not at all what you need to look at or consider. “It seems almost trivial” because you are utterly confused about what you need to prove. To prove that a function is linear you need to show that $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$ and $T(av) = aT(v). Nothing more nothing less (cont)

Comment: (cont) The fact that “whatever $f$ spits out will be a suitable vector for $g$ to act on” is just a statement that the range of the function $f$ is contained in the domain of $g$, and that has **nothing** to do with linearity, vector spaces, or the problem at hand. Finally, again, *bases have nothing to do with it*. If you are focusing on bases, let alone finite ones, then you aren’t looking at what you need to look at. Period. It’s not that you are “overcomplicating” things as you say elsewhere, it’s taht you aren’t doing the correct things at all.

Comment: P.S. I’m not trying to be harsh: I’m trying to be clear; and I’m doing that because it seems, from your comments, that you aren’t getting the point that we are trying to put across.

Comment: I was just trying to explain my thought process, not necessarily trying to argue that you were wrong. But I do appreciate the effort you put in trying to help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm not a fan of this proof, for a number of reasons.

First of all, there doesn't appear to be an assumption that $V, W,$ or $U$ are finite-dimensional, and hence it's not reasonable to assume the existence of (finite) bases. This result does hold for arbitrary vector spaces, so leaning on bases should be unnecessary.

Secondly, and more problematically, you appear to simply be showing that $g(f(v)) \in U$, choosing to express these in terms of bases. The fact that $g(f(v)) \in U$ is essentially part of the assumptions; if $f : V \to W$ and $g : W \to U$, even if $f$ and $g$ are non-linear, then as part of the definition of $g \circ f$, $g(f(v)) \in U$. To answer your comment, you didn't even use the linearity of $f$ or $g$, you just reiterated the fact that they are maps from $V$ to $W$ and $W$ to $U$ respectively.

Linearity is far stronger than this. You need to show additivity and scalar homogeneity. That is, you need to show that, for any $v_1, v_2 \in V$ (not necessarily elements of a basis), and any scalar $a$,
\begin{align*}
g(f(v_1 + v_2)) &= g(f(v_1)) + g(f(v_2)) \\
g(f(av_1)) &= ag(f(v_1)).
\end{align*}
Don't use bases; just use the fact that $f$ is linear, then use the fact that $g$ is linear. The full proof for each additivity and scalar homogeneity should be no longer than $3$ lines each.

Comment: This was very helpful, I definitely overcomplicated things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a transformation which can be represented by a matrix is linear (and vice-versa), you could just multiply the matrices.

At least, this would handle the finite dimensional case.